# Screenshot utility for linux

Tags: linux, screenshot

For a while I've been looking for a good, fast, screenshot tool for Linux. I came down to use [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org), however, I just want something which does the following:

- Click hotkey
- Select what to take a screenshot off
- Click enter
- Upload to FTP in the background
- Give me a notification that the screenshot direct URL is now in my clipboard

Anyone know of some open-source projects, or similar which achieves this? I know Scrot can do some of it, however, I've not been able to make a script which could do this properly for me.

Comment: Why is this marked as community wiki?

Comment: Wrote my own a while ago: http://sirupsen.com/a-simple-imgur-bash-screenshot-utility/

Comment: [Linux-based Screen Capture program?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20541/3579), [What screenshot tools are available?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6558/253474), [Linux screenshot tool that saves shots directly, without asking for a filename](http://superuser.com/q/235957/241386)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like ksnapshot, which comes by default with KDE.

And it can upload to ftp/sftp/fish/etc. easily:

[image: Ksnapshot using FTP]

Comment: Agreed.  KSnapshot is easily the best tool out there.  Not sure about the KDE4 version -- might be better or worse than the KDE3 version I last used.

Comment: This doesn't seem to come with remote uploading though. :/

Comment: Yes it does, because all KDE programs (that I know) support ftp/sftp/fish schemes in their Open/Save boxes. Just put sftp://user@host in the location when saving the file and it should do.

Comment: +1 anything that talks to the GNOME or KDE vfs will happily save-to-upload-via-FTP. GNOME's screenshot tool does the same, though it only offers full-screen or current-window capture.

Comment: +1 - In the KDE4 version you can add the imagebin plasmoid to the desktop, take the screenshot by hitting the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and directly drag it to the plasmoid to give you link to the image. No need to save it on your system